# How to perform mixed-effects linear regression in R?

Tags: r, lme4

I have three independent variables (*x1*, *x2*, *x3*), and one dependent variable (*y*). I carry out *n* experiments, so I have *n* combinations of *x1*, *x2*, *x3*. For each experiment, I set triplicate, so there is *3*n* observations for the *y*.

For reproducible purpose, I give some sample code as below:

```
n <- 10   # experiment size

id <- seq(from=1, to=n, by=1)   # experiment number
x1 <- rnorm(n=n, mean = 1, sd = 1)
x2 <- rnorm(n=n, mean = 10, sd = 1)
x3 <- rnorm(n=n, mean = 10, sd = 10)

df <- cbind(id, x1, x2, x3)

df <- rbind(df, df, df)   # triplicate

df <- transform(df, rep=c(rep("A",times=n), rep("B",times=n), rep("C",times=n)), 
            y = rnorm(n=3*n, mean=5, sd=5))

df <- df[order(df[,"id"]),]

df

fit <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=df)   # a linear regression
summary(fit)
```

**Now I wonder how to perform a mixed-effects linear regression for my experiment data**?

---

**ADD**:
I think I know the answer now:

```
library(lme4)
fit2 <- lmer(y~x1+x2+x3+(1|rep), data=df)   # a mixed-effect linear regression
summary(fit2)
```

Comment: Have you seen the vignette "Fitting linear mixed-effects models" at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html?

Comment: Also [this post on Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet) may contain helpful information

Comment: if you know the answer, please post it *as an answer* - not as an addendum to your question ...